# Validating a user input "string" length (C language)

Tags: c, string, validation, user-input, string-length

I'm trying to make a small program that reads the input from a user, and only accept a String with a length of 1. Also, it must either be a 'm', 'o', 'r', 'i' or 'c'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define CODE_METRO_BUS 'm'
#define CODE_OMNIBUS 'o'
#define CODE_RAPIDE 'r'
#define CODE_INTEGRE 'i'
#define CODE_CARTE_ORANGE 'c'

char userInput[50];

printf("Enter the desired service:\n");
printf("\n");
printf("(Enter M) Metro/Bus\n");
printf("(Enter O) Train/Omnibus\n");
printf("(Enter R) Train rapide\n");
printf("(Enter I) Transport integre\n");
printf("(Enter C) Carte orange\n");
printf("\n");
printf("Choice: ");

fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s",userInput);
while ((userInput!= CODE_METRO_BUS &&
        userInput!= CODE_OMNIBUS &&
        userInput!= CODE_RAPIDE &&
        userInput!= CODE_INTEGRE &&
        userInput!= CODE_CARTE_ORANGE) ||
        (strlen(userInput> 1)) ) {

    printf("Error! Retry: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",userInput);
}
```

I'm just really not sure how I could do it. When I tried by using char, it was half working because, let's say I entered on input "mfybsn", the program just detected the first letter (which is 'm') and it validated as correct. But obviously, "mfybsn" is not = to 'm' even though my old program thinks it was for some reasons.

Now as I said, I'm trying to use strings to only accept "userInput" if it has a length of 1 (and other conditions), but I can't manage to achieve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `strlen(userInput> 1)` doesn’t make sense. Your compiler should have given a warning about this.

Comment: use `strcmp`  to compare strings. At least use userInput[0] to get the first character such that you can compare char.

Comment: What do you expect `char userInput[50]; ... scanf("%s",userInput);` to do should the user enter many characters like 60 or so?

Comment: Do not `fflush(stdin)`. It's undefined behavior in C, and useless where platforms define it.

Answer (score 0):

you want :

```
while ((*userInput!= CODE_METRO_BUS &&
        *userInput!= CODE_OMNIBUS &&
        *userInput!= CODE_RAPIDE &&
        *userInput!= CODE_INTEGRE &&
        *userInput!= CODE_CARTE_ORANGE) ||
        (strlen(userInput) > 1)) ) {
```

because *userInput* is a string while `CODE_METRO_BUS` and others are characters, and a ')' is wrongly placed when you check the length

---

I encourage you to replace `scanf("%s",userInput);` by `scanf("%49s",userInput);` to not write out of *userInput* if the user enter more than 49 characters, even it is strange to read a string up to 49 characters while expecting just 1 char ...

It is also interesting to check the value returned by *scanf* is 1

---

It is also strange to write `Enter M` and to test *m* rather than *M* etc